# How to refresh git diff output in Vim

Tags: git, vim, diff, git-diff

The command I use to check the project diff is

```
git diff | vimdiff -
```

Is there a way I can refresh the diff file without existing Vim and repeating the previous command?

Comment: Why would you use `vimdiff` on standard input? `vimdiff` expects two files. You may simply `git diff | vim -` to get the same effect. Anyway, the command `git diff` is already piped; you have to execute it again if you wish to see how it changes. Consider using other vim tools for that purpose.

Comment: that's simply not true.

Comment: @HansZauber yes, sorry...withdrawn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vim instance only receives the diff information from `stdin` (via the `|` shell pipe), so there's no way to refresh that.

If you don't want to exit Vim and recall the command from the shell history, I would recommend using a plugin (like [fugitive.vim - A Git wrapper so awesome, it should be illegal](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975)) that allows you to trigger (and re-trigger!) a diff from within Vim.

Answer (score 3):

In Vim:

`:%d | .!git diff`

The first part deletes all lines, and the second runs `git diff` in the cwd and pipes the output of this command to the buffer.